# MYSQL Time difference between MAX and MIN from single table

Tags: mysql, max, min

I have a table as outlined below and I'm trying to get the MAX and MIN values for a specific Id but only if the MAX entry date is greater than the MIN entry date.

table:

```
ID  ENTRY_DATE              NAME       PRICE
1   2012-01-23 16:09:35     MONKEY     99.33
2   2012-01-23 11:04:09     MONKEY     97.65
3   2012-01-23 09:31:19     MONKEY     93.05
4   2012-01-23 15:12:14     DICE       30.49
5   2012-01-23 12:01:24     DICE       32.00
6   2012-01-23 08:01:24     DICE       31.00
```

So what I'm trying to do is grab the MAX(price) and MIN(price) when the MAX(price) entry_date is greater than the MIN(price) entry_date. From the table above, my result would be:

```
NAME      MaxPrice     MinPrice   PriceDiff   
MONKEY    99.33        93.05      6.28
```

'Dice' would not show up because the MAX date/time happens before the MIN.

I have tried a LEFT JOIN but I cant seem to figure it out. Here is what I have right now, but it obviously grabs all results as I cant seem to figure out how to compare the entry dates...

```
SELECT name,
MAX(price) as MaxPrice,
MIN(price) as MinPrice,
MAX(price)-MIN(price) AS PriceDiff,
FROM products
WHERE DATE(entry_date) = DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY PriceDiff DESC
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To select the max price per group (& date corresponding to that) you do:

```
SELECT p.NAME, p.ENTRY_DATE as dateofMax, p.PRICE as maxPrice
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products p2
 ON p.NAME=p2.NAME AND p.PRICE<p2.PRICE
WHERE p2.PRICE IS NULL;
```

What this does is JOINs `products` to itself on the `name`, forming every possible pair of prices within each name, where `p.PRICE<p2.PRICE`. Since this is a left join, if there is a price in `p` for which there is no greater price in `p2`, `p2.PRICE` will be set to NULL.

So this query selects the row where there is no greater price, ie the row *of* the max price (per group, being `NAME`).

To select the min price per group (& corresponding date) you change the `<` to a `>` in the `LEFT JOIN`, and so we pick the row for which we can't find any *smaller* price in the table for that name.

Since you wish to pick *both* the max *and* the min, these two tables need to be JOINed together.

### Solution

This means 3 self-joins of `product` to itself, where two `product` tables are used to calculate the max price/date, and the other two are used are used to calculate the min.

In the query below, all lines but the last will produce a table with the max price & its date, and the min price & its date. The last enforces your "price of max happens after price of min" condition.

The `p,p2` tables are used to calculate the max price, and the `p3,p4` to calculate the min price. It would still work if `p3` was joined to `p` `ON p.NAME=p3.NAME` only, but the extra condition `p3.price<=p.price` prunes out rows we're not interested in (there's no point looking for the min price on rows for which the price is greater than the max!).

```
-- select max price & date of max & min price & date of min:
SELECT p.NAME, p.ENTRY_DATE as dateofMax, p.PRICE as maxPrice, 
       p3.ENTRY_DATE as dateofMin, p3.PRICE as minPrice,
       p.PRICE-p3.PRICE as PriceDiff
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products p2
 ON p.NAME=p2.NAME AND p.PRICE<p2.PRICE
LEFT JOIN products p3
 ON p.NAME=p3.NAME AND p3.price<=p.price
LEFT JOIN products p4
 ON p.NAME=p4.NAME AND p3.price>p4.price
WHERE p2.PRICE IS NULL
AND p4.PRICE IS NULL
AND p.ENTRY_DATE>p3.ENTRY_DATE; -- make sure dateOfMax>dateofMin
```

which yields

```
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| NAME   | dateofMax           | maxPrice | dateofMin           | minPrice | PriceDiff |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| MONKEY | 2012-01-23 16:09:35 |    99.33 | 2012-01-23 09:31:19 |    93.05 | 6.28      |
+--------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @mathematical.coffee ! Looks promising. I'm just wondering how I get it to ENTRY_DATE = DATE(NOW())? I tried adding it to the WHERE section for each, so like
`AND DATE(p.ENTRY_DATE) = DATE(NOW())
    AND DATE(p2.ENTRY_DATE) = DATE(NOW())
    AND DATE(p3.ENTRY_DATE) = DATE(NOW())
    AND DATE(p4.ENTRY_DATE) = DATE(NOW())`

Comment: It depends -- if you want the date of max to be NOW you do `p.ENTRY_DATE`, of you want the date of the min to be NOW you do `p3.ENTRY_DATE`. The other two will be NULL (as their corresponding PRICE is NULL), so adding them in to the WHERE won't work.

Comment: Perfect. I added your suggestion for the p3 and p entry date. I have one more issue, for one of my entries the exact same min for the same product is hit multiple times during the day, say
'MONKEY 2012-01-23 16:09:35 0.15'
'MONKEY 2012-01-23 11:09:35 0.15'
So the min shows up twice, therefore creating duplicate rows. Is it possible to return only 1 result then? Thanks a lot for the help and especially the breakdown, that helped a lot understanding the solution.

Comment: You can add a `GROUP BY NAME` to return whichever row occurs "first" in your database (so not predictable) if you don't mind which row gets chosen. Otherwise, if you wanted (say) to pick the most recent or earliest `dateOfMin` you have to join again in a similar fashion to before but using ENTRY_DATE instead of PRICE (and you'll have the same problem with `dateOfMax` too).